# Sending an html email with phpmailer and codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmailer

I am sending emails with phpmailer package and using the package with codeigniter framework. I have made a helper function out of the phpmailer package which takes arguments as sender's address, recipient's address, subject and message body. Everything goes fine and the message is delivered to the inbox.
 My problem is I have a large body which can be a seperate html file. For this I have created a view and I am trying to send the argument $this->load->view('viewname'); through the helper function in my controller. But instead of displaying the body in mail I get the file displayed on my final view page and the mail body goes blank. Any idea how I can achieve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `$this->load->view('viewname');` without any additional parameters will output the view. What you need is to set the third parameter to `TRUE` as suggested in the Returning views as data of the [CodeIgniter User Guide's View documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html).

**Example:**

```
$string = $this->load->view('viewname', '', true);
```